# How to Find the Radius of Convergence for This Proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k}$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

I posted this question a few days ago and was given a clue.  I think that I'm almost there. 
The idea is to divide up the interval $[0,1] = [0, 1-\delta] \cup (1-\delta, 1]$. 
By a proof similar to that of Abel's Theorem, $\sum {a_k}{x^k}$ converges uniformly on $(1-\delta, 1]$. 
By the Weierstrass M-Test, $\sum {a_k}{x^k}$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1-\delta]$. 
Now, Abel's Theorem requires that the radius of convergence of $\sum {a_k}{x^k}$ to be a specific value. 
In this case, the radius of convergence needs to be $1$.  But how do we know that? 
The details below is the proof.

Let $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$, and let $A_{-1} = 0$. Rewrite $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {a_k}{x^k} =$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{A_k}(x^k - x^{k+1}) + {A_n}{x^n} - A_{-1}x^0$$
$$= (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{A_k}x^k + {A_n}{x^n}$$

Since the sequence $(A_k)$ converges and $|x| \lt 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a_k}{x^k} =(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{A_k}x^k$$
Let $A = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a_k}$.  For any given $\epsilon$, select $N_1$ such that $|A_n - A| \lt {\epsilon \over 2}$ for all $n \gt N_1$.
$$\left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a_k}{x^k} - A \right| = \left| (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{A_k}x^k - (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}Ax^k\right|$$
$$ = \left| (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(A_k-A)x^k\right|$$
$$\le (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|A_k-A|x^k$$
$$ = (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N_1}|A_k-A|x^k + (1-x)\sum_{k=N_1+1}^{\infty}|A_k -A|x^k$$
$$ \le (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N_1}|A_k-A| + {\epsilon \over 2}$$
$$= (1-x)M + {\epsilon \over 2}$$
Select $\delta$ such that $x \in (1-\delta, 1) \rightarrow (1-x)M + {\epsilon \over 2} \lt \epsilon$ 
So for all $x \in (1-\delta, 1]$, when $n \gt N_1$, the series converges.

To show that $\sum {a_k}{x^k}$ converges on $[0, 1-\delta]$, let $r = 1-\delta$,
and let $N_2$ be a value such that $n, m > N_2 \rightarrow |a_m| \lt 1$ and $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}r^k \lt \epsilon$.  Then,
$$\left| \sum_{k=m+1}^{n}{a_k}{x^k} \right| \le \sum_{k=m+1}^{n}|a_k|{x^k} \le \sum_{k=m+1}^{n}{r^k} \lt \epsilon$$
For all $x \in [0, 1-\delta]$, when $n \gt N_2$, the series converges.

Comment: Use [Abel's uniform convergence test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel.27s_uniform_convergence_test) at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You did most of the work, you only have to conclude now. The tricky part is actually the $(1-\delta,1]$ interval. Once you have done that, notice that if $|x|\leq 1-\delta$,
$$
    |a_nx^n|\leq M (1-\delta)^n=M_n
$$
and $\sum M_n$ converges, thus, by Weierstrass M-test, the series $\sum a_nx^n$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1-\delta]$. If we write $f$ the pointwise limit of $f_n:x\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$, there exists $N_2$ such that $n>N_2$ implies $||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\epsilon$ for any $x\in[0,1-\delta]$. As you pointed out, if $n>N_1$, then $||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\epsilon$ for any $x\in(1-\delta,1]$.
Consequently, if $n>\max(N_1,N_2)$, $||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\epsilon$ for any $x\in[0,1]$, which concludes the proof.